# Calculating a point with only the distance, a point on the line and gradient of a line

Tags: linear-algebra

[image: I am trying to calculate B]I wondered how to prove a theory I have about calculating a point having only a line and a circle the line is tangent to.
If  $$\Delta{y}^2$$$$\Delta{x}^2$$ Thus the distance between any two integer numbers is $$\sqrt{\Delta{y}^2+\Delta{x}^2}=m$$ After seeing this I decided to "create" my very own formula $$n*r=m$$ where r is the distance between the point on the line, m is the gradient and $$n\Delta{y}(initial)= \Delta{y}(new)$$ and $$n\Delta{x}(initial)=\Delta{x}(new)$$ thus the new point will be $$(x+\Delta{x}(new);y+\Delta{y}(new)) or (x-\Delta{x}(new);y-\Delta{y}(new))$$ I believe it will work for all lines and points with a distance. I am actually afraid to post this here but how can I prove my theory?
In this example I am trying to calculate B.

Comment: Do you want the point of intersection, if one exists, or the closest point to intersection? Sorry, I don't quite understand what you are trying to solve. It seems to be related to the Newton-Raphson methods of solution finding.

Comment: @FundThmCalculus I am trying to find a point on the line that is exactly a given distance away from the given point on a given line I will add an example shortly

Comment: Thanks, I have what I need to give you a solution. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 2D Case

For the simple 2D case, the solution is pretty clear:
$$y=mx+b$$
$$m=\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$$
Given a point $p=(x_0,y_0)$ on the line $y$, Find the point a distance $r$ away. Note that there are two points. Assuming that $r$ has a sign to determine which one you want.

The standard Euclidean distance formula:
$$r=\sqrt{\Delta x^2+\Delta y^2} \leftrightarrow r^2=\Delta x^2+\Delta y^2$$
Expanding the deltas.
$$m=\frac{y_1-y_0}{x_1-x_0}\leftrightarrow (y_1-y_0)=m(x_1-x_0),r^2=(x_1-x_0)^2+(y_1-y_0)^2$$
Plug $m$ into the other formula.
$$r^2=(x_1-x_0)^2+m^2(x_1-x_0)^2=(x_1-x_0)^2(1+m^2)$$
$$x_1-x_0=\frac{r}{\sqrt{1+m^2}}$$
$$x_1=x_0+\frac{r}{\sqrt{1+m^2}}$$
Back substitution gives $y_1$.
$$y_1-y_0=m (x_0+\frac{r}{\sqrt{1+m^2}}-x_0 )$$
$$y_1=y_0+\frac{mr}{\sqrt{1+m^2}}$$

### Vector Solution

LET There be a line paramterized by the following equation:
$$\vec r(t)=\vec r_0+t*\langle r_1,r_2,...,r_n \rangle$$
Where $t$ is the independent parameter, and $\vec v=\langle r_1,r_2,...,r_n \rangle$ are the direction numbers of the line. $\vec r_0$ is a point on the line defined to be the origin of the line.

If the origin of the line is the initial point of interest, solve for the parametric value $t_1$ using the following equations. The final "division" is elementwise. If all the values for $t_1$ that are found by each of the dimensions, then the system is consistent, and the point is on the line.
$$\vec r_1=\vec r_0+t_1*\vec v \leftrightarrow t_1=\frac{\vec r_1-\vec r_0}{\vec v}$$

Repeat this procedure with the second point of interest. We don't know what $t_2$ is yet, but the formula is useful for later, because it too must be true.
$$t_2=\frac{\vec r_2-\vec r_0}{\vec v}$$

This gives the parametric value for each point away from whatever point is chosen as the "origin". Use the Euclidean distance to find the second point as a given distance from the first.
$$D=\|\vec r_2-\vec r_1\|=\|\vec r_0+t_2*\vec v-\vec r_0-t_1*\vec v\|$$
$$=\|t_2*\vec v-t_1*\vec v\|$$
Since $t_1,t_2$ are scalars, the difference can be factored out of the magnitude. Note that it does not give us direction, due to the absolute value sign. Thus, there are two possible solutions to check (one on each side of the point $\vec r_1$.
$$D=|t_2-t_1|\|\vec v\| \leftrightarrow |t_2-t_1|=\frac{D}{\|\vec v\|}$$
Taking this into account, the solutions are found by substituting back into the vector line definition:
$$\vec r_2)_1 = \vec r_0 + t_2)_1 * \vec v$$
$$\vec r_2)_2 = \vec r_0 + t_2)_2 * \vec v$$

Comment: Working on a vector solution that will be generalizable to any number of dimensions.